# Rename a custom object from package using SFDX/Packaging 2

Tags: custom-object, salesforcedx, packaging-2

I'm trying to rename a custom object I created as part of a managed package I created with packaging 2/SFDX. I would also be happy with deleting it and creating a new one.

The problem I'm running into when trying to rename it is that there appears to be something still referencing the object when I attempt to create a new package version after I do the rename. There is nothing in my code referencing the object any more.

Any ideas? Is there any documentation about how to do this is SFDX?

```
➜ sfdx force:package2:version:create:get -i 08XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
=== Package2 Version Create Request
NAME                            VALUE
──────────────────────────────  ──────────────────
ID                              08XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Status                          Error
Package2 Id                     0HXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Package2 Version Id
Subscriber Package2 Version Id
Tag
Branch
Created Date                    2018-02-27 10:43
=== Errors
(1) Old_CustomObject__c: In field: fullName - no CustomObject named 
namespace__Old_CustomObject__c found
```

Comment: Have you checked out the [Packaging 2 Trailblazer Community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000Lg5U)? (Might require signing in to view.) It's super active and the Packaging 2 project lead is routinely commenting there. [Here's some packaging docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm), if you haven't found them already.